# R: Getting a value from a table based on a loop

Tags: r

I have a loop where I am trying to build a table by grabbing information from a driver table I import. What I'm stuck on is I want to loop through columns based on a loop, something like:

In the first loop through I want it to function like 
`df$a <- Driver$M1[i]`
and then in the second loop through function like 
`df$a <- Driver$M2[i]` and so on

Through searching I thought I had come across the solution of

`df$a <- get(paste0("Driver$M",j,"[i]"))` but I get the error 
`object 'Driver$M1[i]' not found`
so I don't think "get" functions like I thought it did.

Could someone help me find out how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show that piece of code that's giving you trouble?   The table too.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the columns of a table "smoke"

```
> smoke
          High Low Middle
  current   51  43     22
  former    92  28     21
  never     68  22      9
```

is as simple as

```
> for (i in colnames(smoke)) {t = smoke[,i]; print(i); print(t)}
[1] "High"
current  former   never
     51      92      68
[1] "Low"
current  former   never
     43      28      22
[1] "Middle"
current  former   never
     22      21       9
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone looking at this, I kept looking and came across writing it in a different way. Writing it this way seems to do what I was looking for: `Driver[i,paste0("M",j)]`

I'm not very experienced so I don't want to be sharing incorrect information but it seems like the $ function cant accept variables but by changing the way its written to Driver[row, column] column is looking for a string anyway so paste0() now works like I want it too.